# How to install PHP FPM on CentOs 5.6

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, php-fpm

I am trying to install PHP FPM on my CentOS 5.6 server, but I wasn't able to get it to work. After downloading PHP 5.3.20 from their php.net, configuring it, making it and installing it, I got this message:

```
Installing PHP SAPI module:       fpm
Installing PHP CLI binary:        /usr/bin/
Installing PHP CLI man page:      /usr/share/man/man1/
Installing PHP FPM binary:        /usr/sbin/
Installing PHP FPM config:        /etc/
Installing PHP FPM man page:      /usr/share/man/man8/
Installing PHP FPM status page:      /usr/share/fpm/
Installing build environment:     /usr/lib/build/
Installing header files:          /usr/include/php/
Installing helper programs:       /usr/bin/
  program: phpize
  program: php-config
Installing man pages:             /usr/share/man/man1/
  page: phpize.1
  page: php-config.1
```

At that point, I assumed PHP was installed so I restarted Apache, but it was serving PHP files as plain text. How do I fix this? How do I get PHP FPM enabled on my CentOS 5.6 box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for apache to act as a reverse proxy, using php-fpm as the backend application server.

1. Ensure that php-fpm configured and running: `service php-fpm restart` and check logs for failure
2. Ensure that somewhere in your apache config, you have loaded the correct proxying modules:
3. Also, you need to include a proxypass directive so apache knows where to send the request for fulfillment.

Part of your apache config might look something like this, assuming php-fpm is running on port 9000:

```
LoadModule  proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule  proxy_fcgi_module    modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName    localhost
  DocumentRoot  "/var/www/html"
  ProxyPass     ProxyPass /myapp/ fcgi://localhost:9000
</VirtualHost>
```

If this is not sufficient, update your question with more information about your apache config and you php-fpm config and exactly what commands you're running and the results you get.